# Trigonometry System of Equations

Tags: trigonometry

If $\textstyle \tan x$ +$\textstyle \tan y$=24 
and $\textstyle \cot x$ + $\textstyle \cot y$=28

compute $\textstyle \tan (x+y)$

I've tried various approaches to doing this including, using the tangent sum of two angles formula as well as various attempts at systems of equations, to no avail. The answer must be an integer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

let $\tan x = a, \tan y= b.$  then you have $$a+b = 24, 1 = \frac 1 a + \frac 1 b = \frac{a+b}{ab} = 28$$ so you have $$ab = \frac 67.$$

now, $$\tan (x + y) = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1 - \tan x \tan y} = \frac{a+b}{1 - ab} = \frac{24}{1 - \frac 67}=168 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$28=\cot x+\cot y=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{\tan x\tan y}=\frac{24}{\tan x\tan y}$$
Therefore
$$\tan x\tan y=\frac67$$

Now
$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}=\frac{24}{1-\frac67}$$

Answer (score 1):

Provided that
$$a+b=24,\qquad \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=28 $$
we have $ab=\frac{6}{7}$, so:
$$\frac{a+b}{1-ab} = 7(a+b) = \color{red}{168}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use a bit of shorthand taking liberty with functional notation ( Looks like being lazy, but still works)

$$ tx + ty  = 24; \;  \frac {1}{ tx} + \frac {1}{ ty } =  28$$

Bring second one to a common denominator and transpose

$$ tx \cdot ty = \frac{24}{28} = \frac{6}{7}  $$  so that

$$ t(x + y) = \frac{tx + ty}{1 - tx \cdot ty}  = \frac{24}{1 - \frac 67}=168. $$